# What is the big-$O$ notation of a summation of a log?

Tags: big-o-notation

For:
$$\sum^{n+m}_{i=n} \log(i)$$
I'm wondering what the big O notation is and how to prove it...
I believe that we can also write this as 
$$\log(n) + \log(n+1) + \log(n + 2) + \ldots + \log(n+m)$$

also $$\log(n+m)!/\log(n-1)!$$

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that the sum of $\log$'s is equivalent to the $\log$ of products.

That is:

$$\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$$

Thus we can change your function:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=n}^{n+m} \log i &= \log \prod_{i = n}^{n + m} i\\
&= \log (n \cdot (n+1) \cdot (n+2) \cdot \ldots \cdot (m-1) \cdot m )\\
&= \log (m!\ /\ (n-1)! )\\
\end{align}
$$

Then we can similarly use the division rule to get these back out:

$$
\log (m!\ /\ (n-1)! ) = \log (m!) - \log((n-1)!)
$$

Then using [Stirling's Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) we can immediately see:

$$
\log (m!) - \log((n-1)!) = O(m \log m)
$$

You might be able to do better though by taking more precise bounds to get:

$$
\begin{align}
\log (m!) - \log((n-1)!) &\leq em^{m + \frac{1}{2}}e^{-m} - \sqrt{2\pi}(n-1)^{n- \frac{1}{2}}e^{1-n}\\
&= \vdots
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

O((m +1) log(n+m)). It’s obviously an upper bound. But also most values have a logarithm close to the maximum, so it’s also a good lower bound.

In your particularly simple case, the Stirling formula will give you a better result, but you asked for big-O only.

Comment: Thanks so much -- so the big O is O(m+1)log(n+m)). ... sorry, but could you show why...I understand the log(n+m) part but not sure I understand where m+1 came from