# What is the big-$O$ notation of a summation of logs where the arguments add to $n$?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation

For:
$$\sum^{k}_{i=1} \log(x_i)$$
where:
$$\sum^{k}_{i=1} x_i = n$$
Is there any big-$O$ result in terms of $n$ ?

I found [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/125776/what-is-the-big-o-notation-of-a-summation-of-a-log), but is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show that $\prod_{i = 1}^{n}x_i$ is maximized when all $x_i$'s are equal, i.e., $x_i = n/k$ for every $i \in \{1,\dotsc,k\}$.

Therefore, $$\sum_{i = 1}^{k} \log x_i = \log \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{k} x_i \right) \leq \log \left( \prod_{i = 1}^{k} \frac{n}{k} \right) = k \log (n/k) \leq n = O(n)$$

Thanks to @JohnL. for pointing out that $k\log_{e}(n/k) \leq n$.

Comment: Yes, since $k\log(n/k)\le \frac ne$, for $n\ge e$.

Comment: @JohnL. Thanks! Can we also say that $k \log (n/k) \leq n$ for any value of $n$? I think so.

Comment: Of course, since $\log(n/k)\lt0$ if $n\lt e$.  (The base for $\log$ here and above is $e$).

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Thanks for the answer, how do you prove that the multiplication is maximum when the values are equal?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Take a look at Jensen's inequality. If you want to prove it from scratch take two factors $a$ and $b$ such that $a<b$ and compare the product $a \cdot b$ with the product $(a+\varepsilon) \cdot (b-\varepsilon)$ for some sufficiently small $\varepsilon > 0$ (notice that the *sum* of the factors stays the same).